# Range for loop doesn't work when operating with an indexed element

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, auto

I was not sure how to frame the title but the explanation is simpler.
I was playing with the c++11 range for loops ([link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)).

I wrote the following:

```
for(auto &elem:vec){
    elem/=vec[0];
}
```

Which compiles but does not change anything in the vector 'vec'.

This, on the other hand, works:

```
elem0 = vec[0];
for(auto &elem:vec){
    elem/=elem0;
}
```

Is this expected? What is wrong with the first method? If it helps, my compiler version is g++ 4.6.3.

Comment: `for(auto &elem:vec)` is the weirdest formatting I have ever seen applied to this syntax. Why not `for (auto& elem : vec)` like they do in the Standard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually it works just fine except that, in your example, `vec[0]` has been changed to `1` after the first run, which makes the remaining runs look like *"not working"* (remain the same value if divided by `1`).

You will see it clearly by using the following example (will work *"as expected"*):

```
vector<float> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
for (auto &elem : vec){
    elem /= vec[4];
}

// now vec={0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0}
```

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that. Thanks. That answers my question.